# Is it possible to move from one ViewController to another by using URLScheme?

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, url-scheme

I'm working on a project that user can opens the app from outside and showing ProductViewController (a ViewController that shows the specific product with some info like  name, mode, price and ...) for this part, I using this func inside AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

I wanted to put some shortcuts button inside app, that when the user tapping on that button, can reach to the same product in ProductViewController too.(imagine after one time a user by a product I put some shortcut so the user can find that product fast) I know I can do this by using this code:

```
let productVC = ProductViewController()
present(productVC, animated: true)
```

but I want to know can I use that part of codes(inside AppDelegate for doing this too).
I did't want to use the both ways to doing one job.

Comment: Right idea, but probably the wrong way around. Your code in the app delegate should decode the product data from the URL and then call a function to present the product VC. From within your app you can just call that function. There is no need to add the overhead of a URL.

Comment: yes you are right and I know that, but do you think is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sure. Why not?  It's your code. You already have the code that moves to a vc once you retrieve the product details. Just call that when you need to.

Comment: no I mean the way that I asked in my question :)

Comment: It might be possible, but I don't see the benefit. It just adds a lot of complexity for no good reason.

Comment: can you tell me how can I do this? you don't need to write some codes just tell me using which way?

Comment: It really depends on how your apps view hierarchy is structured. Essentially you need to present a new view controller. This could be modal or via a navigation controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have a button inside your app call openURL (or rather `application(_:open:options)`) with a URL that invokes a private URL scheme. You'd then have your app delegate decode the URL, figure out what view controller the URL specifies, and open that view controller.

Just have the IBAction for your button invoke `application(_:open:options)` with your custom URL. You could use something like:

`myApp://open?VC=ProductViewController`

Where open is a verb your app looks for to tell it to open a view controller, and the `VC` query parameter tells it which VC to open.

What is it you want help with, exactly?

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted to know. thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Like PaulW, I don't really see the benefit to this however. Have a shared function that takes a view controll identifier, and uses it to instantiate and display that view controller. Call that function from your URL encoder and from your button IBAction. That is better than having your button invoke `OpenURL()`

Comment: I don't understand why you think this is not a good idea? with this way I just one time handling which viewController to open (inside AppDelegate), when coming from outside of the app by URL Scheme or by tapping a shortcut button.